# passing a list to a where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to export from SQL to .csv and it works if I hard code it to accept a certain number of arguments. The things is, I want to allow the user to request any number of arguments and have these be passed to the where clause. The code should make this a bit more clear.

```
create temporary table bdates as

 select tt.date, tt.time, tt.location
 from birthdays as bd
 inner join days as d
   on (d.id = bd.birth_id)
 inner join total_time as tt
   on (bd.date = tt.date and
       bd.time = tt.time and
       d.day_of = tt.location)
 where tt.date in(:date1, :date2) --defined by user at command line
 order by...

\copy bdates to '.csv'
```

So what I think I want to do is pass a list to that where clause instead of explicit :dates# variables. For example, a person could run the script with the argument '2012-01-04 12:00, 2012-02-04 12:00, 2012-03-04 12:00', or just two arguments or one. In the case of three the string would be parsed to '2012-01-04 12:00', '2012-02-04 12:00', '2012-03-04 12:00'.

I've tried string_to_array(), unnest(regexp_matches(:dates, expression)) and regexp_split_to_table(:dates, expression), though I'm not sure how to do the join. the various solutions I've tried have produced numerous errors including:

cannot cast type text[] to timestamp without time zone

cannot cast type record to timestamp without time zone

regexp_split does not support the global option

argument of WHERE must not return a set

The last one is especially disheartening and I'm at a loss and would appreciate any input. There's a simpler way to do this, isn't there?  Thanks!

Comment: you don't need regex, just put a curly bracket around the string, then cast it to `timestamp[]` array

Comment: And cannot use IN for array. You must use equal and ANY. `WHERE expr = ANY(arrayHere)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table x(d timestamp);

insert into x values
('jan 2, 2012'),
('february 4, 2012 12:00'),
('jan 4, 2012 12:00'),
('march 1, 2012'),
('may 3, 2012');
```

Query:

```
with input as
(
  select 
  '2012-1-2, 2012-01-04 12:00, 2012-02-04 12:00, 2012-03-04 12:00'::text
  as d_input
)
,converted_to_array as
(
  select ('{' || d_input || '}')::timestamp[] as d_array
  from input 
)
select d
from x cross join converted_to_array
where d = any(d_array)
```

Output:

```
D
January, 02 2012 00:00:00-0800
February, 04 2012 12:00:00-0800
January, 04 2012 12:00:00-0800
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/43d48/26

---

You can also use IN, just unnest array to rows:

```
with input as
(
  select 
  '2012-1-2, 2012-01-04 12:00, 2012-02-04 12:00, 2012-03-04 12:00'::text
  as d_input
)
,converted_to_array as
(
  select ('{' || d_input || '}')::timestamp[] as d_array
  from input 
)
select d
from x cross join converted_to_array
where d in (select unnest(d_array))
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/43d48/29

---

You can put them all in one line too:

```
select d
from x 
where d in (select unnest( ('{' || '2012-1-2, 2012-01-04 12:00, 2012-02-04 12:00, 2012-03-04 12:00'::text || '}')::timestamp[] ))
```

But I hesitates to do so, as it causes horizontal scrollbar here on stackoverflow :-)

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/43d48/31

Comment: Hey, thank you this looks promising. I'll have a closer look in the morning.

Comment: awesome. it works. thanks for the multiple approaches, I've been working with sql for just two days and it'll be good to figure out how each of these is working. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the simplest and fastest method:

Test table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t(d date);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
 ('2012-1-1')
,('2012-1-4')
,('2012-2-2')
,('2012-2-4')
,('2012-3-3')
,('2012-3-4');
```

As you are filtering on dates, not timestamps, you can simplify your example input:

```
'2012-01-04 12:00, 2012-02-04 12:00, 2012-03-04 12:00'
```

to:

```
'2012-01-04, 2012-02-04, 2012-03-04'
```

Query (works with either input):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   t
JOIN  (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(
                    '2012-01-04, 2012-02-04, 2012-03-04', ', ')::date[]) AS d
    ) x USING (d)
```

Could also be done with:

```
       SELECT regexp_split_to_table(
                       '2012-01-04, 2012-02-04, 2012-03-04', ', ')::date AS d
```

But `regexp_split_to_table()` is slower.
Generally, a `JOIN` is faster to select rows than the relatively slow `IN()`.